# Scattering angle center of mass

Tags: scattering

It may be a silly question but I don't see why all the drawings in the books represent the scattering  [image]

Will I have made a mistake if I represented the scattering in this way ?
[image]

It should be the same thing, I mean theta is aribitrary right?
Or is it wrong in the second picture cause the particles go "backwards" ?

Comment: The scattering angle $\theta$ is measured relative to the direction of the first (incoming) particle and has a range from $0$ to $2\pi$ radians.  There is nothing wrong with your second diagram but it is not the one which is used.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the two diagrams are equivalent if I do a pi rotation of one of them to make the other the for the second angle is the first plus a 180 degrees thanks